# Regex to accept special characters only with alpha numeric

Tags: regex

I created the following regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 ']{1,24}\r?$
```

It should accept alphanumeric, space and apostrophe. And the input should be minimum 1 character and maximum 24 characters.But it accepts inputs with only apostrophe and space also(e.g. `" ' ' "`). I’m expecting to accept apostrophe and space only with some alphanumeric characters. So below test cases should pass

**Pass**

```
Test
Test'My Regex
Test' 123' Regex '
```

**Fail**

- `''`
- 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?=.{1,24}$)[a-zA-Z0-9 ']*[A-Za-z][a-zA-Z0-9 ']*$
```

Or, if strings with just a single digit already make them valid:

```
^(?=.{1,24}$)[a-zA-Z0-9 ']*[A-Za-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ']*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jg0sot/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{1,24}$)` - the whole string must contain 1 to 24 chars
- `[a-zA-Z0-9 ']*` - 0+ alphanumeric, space or `'` chars
- `[A-Za-z]` - an alpha char (**NOTE** replace with `[A-Za-z0-9]` to also allow strings with just a digit)
- `[a-zA-Z0-9 ']*` - 0+ alphanumeric, space or `'` chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: how should I change the regex to support Unicode characters. I mean if I need to support languages like French or Spanish?

Comment: I checked same test cases in regex101.com and it is not working as expected. None of the works are matching

Comment: @user3771120 I [doubt you tested what I suggested](https://regex101.com/r/jg0sot/2).